# Typescript Protractor : Unable to right-click on element

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am using TypeScript in protractor. I am able to click on the element but am unable to right-click. It does not show any error message when attempting to right-click the element.

```
let roleList = element.all(by.xpath(".//table//tr/td[text()= 
    'PRECIOUS.E01']"));
     await roleList.filter(function (ele) {
     return ele.isDisplayed();
     }).then(async function (roleList) {
    console.log('Is displayed ********');
    await roleList[0].click(); console.log('Click perforemed');
    // I tried this first
    // await browser.actions().click( roleList[0], 
    protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
   // Then I tried this
    await  browser.actions().mouseMove(roleList[0]).perform(); await 
    browser.sleep(1000);
    await browser.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform()
    await browser.sleep(5000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal click() belongs to IWebElement interface. Here you can try with ActionSequence Class for performing right click action.
For example -

```
new ActionSequence(browser.driver).
    click(roleList[0],Button.RIGHT).
    perform();
```

Note: Ensure that roleList[0] type is webElement.